# How can I transform Excel imported data to use Plotly 3D surface graph?

Tags: r, excel, matrix, 3d, plotly

I'm new here and relatively new to R.

I'd like to transform a heat map to a surface 3D plot.

I have an excel file with 2 columns: Date (day/mmmm/year hour: min) and Conversion rate average every hour (t/h)
I managed to create heat map with mutate (day(date), month(date, label=true) to create X in hour, Y=days and value my conversion rate. Facet for month/year.

Now for one month, I'd like to use surface 3D, with X: hour, y: days, and Z: conversion rate

How can I transform for my data frame from excel, to this to create 3D surface (like the volcano example)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question so that it contains a minimal, reproducible example. That others will understand what you are trying to do and can offer targetted help. Read this guide first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to get what I wanted.

```
df<-test3  # test3 is a import file from exel, with two columns, date and conversion rate
df <- df %>% mutate(year = year(date),
month = month(date, label=TRUE),
day = day(date), hour=hour(date))   #Transform to date, month, day, hour, conversion rate

df2020<-filter(df,year==2020)
dfabr<-filter(df2020,month=="abr")   #Filter for year 2020 and month april , looks like this

stationid             day  hour month  year  rate
   <chr>               <int> <int> <ord> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Tasa Fusión HF, t/h     1     0 abr    2020 127. 
 2 Tasa Fusión HF, t/h     1     1 abr    2020 130. 
 3 Tasa Fusión HF, t/h     1     2 abr    2020 130. 

---
**df_4=data.frame("x"=c(dfabr$day),"y"=c(dfabr$hour),"z"=c(dfabr$rate))** #Imported and filtered data to MATRIX

library(reshape2)  #for use in plotly 3d surface graphs like volcano example

**df3d<-acast(df_4,x~y, value.var="z",sum)**  #acast return matrix format, I add SUM because with a large data, i got message "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length", I have no idea why, but when i used a small dataset with exact same code, i didn't get that. When i added "sum", error message disapeared 

library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(z = df3d, type = "surface")
p
```

It worked! x is for hours of the dat, y is for days of a month, z is for conversion rate value.
[image]